# Strange pattern-matching: is it correct?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

Why does this function always succeed? It always returns `True` with any values and any types. Is this the correct behavior?

```
f a b = case a of b -> True; _ -> False
```

Comment: The `b` in `b -> True` is a locally scoped variable that "hides" the outer `b` in the `f` definition level. The pattern you use is `b`, and pattern matching with a variable will always succeed.

Comment: Moral of the story: don't forget to add `-Wall`.

Comment: OP: `Is this the correct behavior?` What behavior were you expecting? You should have shared your hypothesis in the question :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just in addition to the perfect answer accepted, my two cents:

this:

```
f a b = case a of b -> True; _ -> False -- (A)
```

and this:

```
f a b = case a of
                c -> True
                _ -> False --(B)
```

are is equivalent to:

```
f a b = case a of
    _ -> True
```

or

```
f a b = True
```

or

```
f _ b = True
```

So, be careful because that's the real behavior you created, a function that takes two parameters and returns always True.

> Also:

**(A)** and **(B)** will show this warning if `-Woverlapping-patterns` is used:

```
warning: [-Woverlapping-patterns]
    Pattern match is redundant
    In a case alternative: _ -> ...
  |
3 |               _ -> False
  |               ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 24):

The `b` in the case definition is *not* the `b` in in the head of the `f` definition. You created a *new locally scoped variable*. Your code is thus equivalent to:

```
f a b = case a of
    c -> True
    _ -> False
```

Pattern matching with a variable indeed always succeeds.

If you want to check if two values are the same, you will need to define some function (or let Haskell automatically derive `Eq` for example).

> **Note**: you can turn on the `-Wname-shadowing` warning to let the compiler warn you about creating identifiers that shadow existing ones. For example your code will produce:
>
> ```
> Prelude> f a b = case a of b -> True; _ -> False
>
> <interactive>:1:19: warning: [-Wname-shadowing]
>     This binding for ‘b’ shadows the existing binding
>       bound at <interactive>:1:5
> ```

Comment: Marvelous as always, but now I could add my two cents :)